# MySQL ignore html characters. Why?

Tags: mysql

Copy:

[image]

Paste and nothing:-

[image]

Why?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a SPACE in the end of your ***title***, try to use **LIKE** instead of **=** :

```
Select * from 'blog_blogshop' where 'title' like '%Proceed to%';
```

Hope this Helps.